# docker compose exec mysqldump prints sql instead of writing it

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a `mysqldump` from inside the `db` service of my Docker Compose app.

Problem: Instead of dumping the file to `/tmp/mydb.sql`, it is printing the output to the screen.

Here is my command: `docker compose exec db mysqldump -uroot mydb > /tmp/mydb.sql`

There is no file in /tmp when this command is done running. I also confirmed that /tmp is writable.

How can I have the command write to `/tmp/mydb.sql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the shell redirection can be tricky because by default, it is interpreted by the shell where you ran the `docker` command, not the shell inside the container.

If you want to ensure the output is redirected by the mysqldump command inside the container, I suggest you use mysqldump with the [`--result-file=/tmp/mydb.sql` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file) (see the link for documentation) instead of getting confused with shell redirection.